# Triggering an event after a specified number of clicks

Tags: c#

So I'm working on my first big C# project and am currently trying to do the following. On the screen is a red stimulus, which after being clicked five times must emit an event. Let's say in this case display a MessageBox. I know how to get MessageBoxes to display information on a button click, however, as mentioned, I want this one to show up after five clicks. I've scrounged the internet for weeks now and have not found anything suitable.

Here is the code I have where clicking on the stimulus yields the MessageBox with only one click.

```
private void AutoSPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
}

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Clicking once"); 
}
```

Note I've only included the Panel and the stimulus. All other code in my program has not been included.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you can take a counter and  check counter%5==0 then fire your code.counter should be declared as class variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this for example:

```
private int counter = 0;
public event EventHandler Clicked5TimesEvent;

private void OnClicked5TimesEvent() {
  if (Clicked5TimesEvent != null) {
       Clicked5TimesEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  counter++;
  if (counter % 5 == 0) {
      OnClicked5TimesEvent();
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks. My only other question is that if I click quickly it doesn't seem to register all clicks. Would I need to redefine it as a doubleclick? (I ask because this is a program that will detect a pigeon's pecking and pigeons tend to peck very rapidly at a highly preferred stimulus.)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a global counter :

```
int numClicks = 0;

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (numClicks >= 5)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Clicking once");
        numClicks = 0;
    }
    else
        numClicks++;
}
```

Comment: I cant find errors in your comment or the question. Can you re-post ?

Comment: But you don't have an accepted answer for this question yet. Would you mind accepting an answer, which you used to solve your problem ?